# php artisan:rollback error in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-migrations

I tried building a database where I forgot to place the index of the table. Now I'm trying to rollback the migration but its not working out. It is throwing some error

> [ErrorException]  Undefined index: 2017_01_06_195028_create_users_themes_table

Now I tried deleting it manually so I deleted the migration file from the database folder and then did `composer dump-autoload`, and then did `rollback` it is still showing same error. Also when this didn't happened I tried placing `index` in the `table` through `phpmyAdmin`, it ain't helped! Still i deleted the table manually and tried doing `composer dump-autoload` and `rollback` it still has same error.

Help me out with this.

Comment: Could be an issue with the migration table. Look for my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I'm having my migration files in different folder so everytime I'm doing a `php artisan migrate rollback` I need to specify the path of those migration file that is why it is showing undefined Index error.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup DB data (if any), drop DB and create it again and run `php artisan migrate` command. It's the easiest way to fix this I guess.

Another thing you could try is to delete last batch from `migrations` table and drop tables from last batch and run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `php artisan migrate`, `migration` table is created and it records the order of the migration you run. And when you `rollback` the list get cleared in the order of rollbacks..

In your case since you got an error the record corresponding to your migration probably still in the `migration` table.

Now if you wish to update your migration file and `migrate` again, you needs to manually clear the corresponding record from the `migration` table. Most probably it would be the last record in the `migration` table.

Clear out that record, fix your migration file and run your migration. You should be good to go.